QField not able to load password protected WMS and WFS layers
I am building a system where a QField user would be able to edit a point layer that is stored in PostGIS database and shared to the QField/QGIS workspace through a password protected WFS-T connection in GeoServer. I also need to use a basemap that is added to the workspace through a password protected WMS service. Both layers work well in QGIS environment, but when I try to open the project in QField, QField fails to open the password protected WFS-T and WMS layers. All other layers, including open WMS layers work well.
Here's what I have done
I have added the password protected WFS-T and WMS layers to the project and uploaded the project to the QField cloud. I have then followed the authentication instructions given on the QField website (https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/authentication/). In other words, I have made a configuration XML file of the username and password of the WMS and WFS services and taken it to the \Android\data\ch.opengis.qfield\files\QField\auth folder in my Android device.
What I expected to happen
The project should upload normally with all the layers in it.
What happens
The project opens open WMS layers and geopackage layers normally but QField fails to load the password protected WFS-T and WMS layers. An error message window is shown. The error window shows the correct login credentials and the correct address to the GeoServer from which the layers are brought to the project. In other words, QField should be able to connect to the services but it is not.
The error window is shown below:

The question in short
How can I make my WFS-T and WMS connections work? Are there some settings that I have not noticed that needs to be changed in order to make the layers work?
Program versions I use
QGIS 3.28.7 and QField 3.3.11
